# Вывод маркеров на карту

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Выводится 4 маркера по нажатию кнопки, хочу сделать чтобы они выводились сразу по открытию карты без нажатия кнопки, но поочередно.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="floating-panel">
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop(true)">Drop Markers</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
<script>
      var neighborhoods = [
        {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
        {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
        {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
        {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
      ];

      var markers = [];
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
        });
      }

      function drop() {
        clearMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
          addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i *500);
        }
      }

      function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          }));
        }, timeout);
      }

      function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
      }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBw624GoeHIzq0UT1o7V6CK-SNAE1xyBRk&callback=initMap"async defer>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```